# Tricky Javascript logic with Objects, Array and Booleans

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objects

I am having a lot of issue trying to figure out this logic.  Let me set the stage here:

In the HTML there are some form/input elements type radio.  Each of them have an ID assigned to it.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="oneAllowed" id="yesterday" />
  <input type="radio" name="oneAllowed" id="today" />
  <input type="radio" name="oneAllowed" id="tomorrow" />
</form>
```

Using Javascript essentially what I am trying to do is loop through the 3 objects, since they all have same name assigned within HTML only a single one can be selected, whichever one is returning true I want grab hold of that result then access the second key:value pair, for example for 'commitYesterday' it would be 'commitYesterday.hasValue();' and dispatch that to a different function for other calculation.

```
var urgentOrderSelector = function(){

    var commitYesterday = {
        isChecked: document.getElementById("yesterday").checked,
        hasValue: function(){
            if (this.isChecked == true) {
                return 3;
            };
        };
    };

    var commitToday = {
        isChecked: document.getElementById("today").checked,
        hasValue: function(){
            if (this.isChecked == true) {
                return 2;
            };
        };
    };

    var commitTomorrow = {
        isChecked: document.getElementById("tomorrow").checked,
        hasValue: function(){
            if (this.isChecked == true) {
                return 1;
            };
        };
    };

    var urgentArray = [commitYesterday.isChecked, commitToday.isChecked, commitTomorrow.isChecked];

    for(var i = 0; i <= urgentArray.length-1; i++){
        if (urgentArray[i].isChecked == true) {

            //This is where I am stuck.  I was thinking of doing perhaps the following:
            return urgentArray[i].hasValue();
        };
    }


};
```

Comment: You're putting the value of the `isChecked` property directly into the "urgentArray", so the attempts to access the `isChecked` property of each array element will fail.

Comment: 2 questions (because I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do): 1) Is returning the value of the 'checked' element important? 2) are you simply trying to determine which radio is checked?

Comment: I am simply trying to check which radio is checked.  Based on that I can make determination on what value to attach to it and continue with the program.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you change your HTML to this:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="oneAllowed" id="yesterday" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="oneAllowed" id="today" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="oneAllowed" id="tomorrow" value="1" />
</form>
```

And use document.querySelector to get the selected elements:

```
document.querySelector('[type="radio"][name="oneAllowed"]:checked').value
```

If you actually need to run specific functions dependend on which radio box is checked you could add an attribute `data-fn="fnName"` to each input and then create an object with the keys as functions:

```
var fns = {'fnName1': function () {}, 'fnName2': function() {} …};
```

And then call the function defined by the Attribute:

```
fns[document.querySelector('[type="radio"][name="oneAllowed"]:checked').getAttribute('data-fn')]();
```

Comment: You can access the `value` attribute as a property of the DOM node; no need to call `.getAttribute()`. Otherwise this is really what the OP should be doing I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this shortly.

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly sure what your end goal is.

But here's a more minified version of your logic. Hope it helps.

```
var urgentOrderSelector = function(){
  var radioDict = {'yesterday':3, 'today':2, 'tomorrow':1};
  return radioDict[$('input[name=oneAllowed]:checked').attr('id')];
};
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to execute some function based on the selection, you could store the function pointers and execute them accordingly, ie:

```
var funcYesterday = function(){alert('yesterday');};
var funcToday = function(){alert('today');};
var funcTomorrow = function(){alert('tomorrow');};

var funcUrgentOrder = function(){
  var radioDict = {
      'yesterday' : funcYesterday, 
      'today'     : funcToday, 
      'tomorrow'  : funcTomorrow
  };
  return radioDict[$('input[name=oneAllowed]:checked').attr('id')]();
};
```

Or, much simpler, since you are using the 'value' property on your radios:

```
function urgentOrderSelector = function() {
    return $('input[name=oneAllowed]:checked').val(); 
};
```

Comment: Nowhere did the OP mention that he is using any Javascript Framework. `$` is not available.

Comment: Yea this is for learning purposes, I did not reach jQuery or any of that yet.